# Magento CE 1.8.1 - Write template to page via Ajax Controller function causes blank html result?

Tags: product, template, controllers, ajax

I am trying to write some HTML back to the page via ajax, called from a custom controller.

The Ajax executes correctly but when I try and retrieve the template and write it to the page, the HTML output is always blank. I cannot figure out how to retrieve the template successfully to write it's contents to the page.

My Controller:
MyModule/Ajax/controllers/ProductController.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';

class MyModule_Ajax_ProductController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController { 

    public function indexAction() {

        if ($product = $this->_initProduct()) {

            $product->getData();
            $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');

            $json_product = array('name' => ''.$helper->htmlEscape($product->getName()).'',
                        'url' => ''.$product->getProductUrl().'',
                        'description' => ''.nl2br($product->getShortDescription()).'',
                        'price' => ''.$product->getFormatedPrice().'');         

            $layout = $this->getLayout();
            $update = $layout->getUpdate();
            $update->load('ajax_product_changestyle'); //loading custom handle defined in module's layout .xml file
            $layout->generateXml();
            $layout->generateBlocks();
            $output = $layout->getOutput();

            //$output always seems to be an empty string?!

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('html' => $output)));


        } else {
            echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product not found');
        }
    }
}
```

My layout XML:
layout/mymodule_ajax.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <ajax_product_changestyle>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <block type="ajax/product" name="root" output="toHtml" template="ajax/product/changestyle.phtml"/>
    </ajax_product_changestyle>
</layout>
```

My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Ajax>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </MyModule_Ajax>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <ajax>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyModule_Ajax</module>
                    <frontName>ajax</frontName>
                </args>
            </ajax>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <ajax>
                    <file>mymodule_ajax.xml</file>
                </ajax>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If the page is rendered blank, do you have any errors in your error log?

Comment: Hello, I was getting no errors but found my problem to be placing the template file in the incorrect folder structure/location.. rather than telling me it couldn't find the tempalte, Magento was returning an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register block in the following way

```
<global>
<blocks>
    <ajax>
        <class>MyModule_Ajax_Block</class>
    </ajax>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Adding the block registration doesn't help.

Comment: It turns out this did partially resolve it - I had also named the structure of my template folder incorrectly which I have outlined in a separate answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was due to the incorrect folder structure of my template file - the system couldn't find the template and hence was returning a blank string (rather than telling me it couldn't find the file).

My folder/file structure for my template was 
template/ajax/product.phtml when it should have been template/mymodule_ajax/product.phtml

Registering the block as Sohel suggested helped too.
Hope this helps others out there who also experience the same result.